# Get same CSS property value of 64 classes with pure Js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, selector

I have created 64 color buttons in dom by js. they have class name like this:

```
c1
c2
c3
c4
```

and so on..

I have created this by this codes:

```
var eg_color_ul_1 = $('.eg-ul-1');
var eg_color_ul_2 = $('.eg-ul-2');

for (var linum = 1; linum < 65; linum++) {
    var Cselector = ".c" + linum;
    var colorMenu = $(Cselector).css( "background-color" );

    eg_color_ul_1.append("<a class=\"c" + linum + "\" color-code=\""+ colorMenu +"\"></a>"),
    eg_color_ul_2.append("<a class=\"c" + linum + "\" color-code=\""+ colorMenu +"\"></a>");

}
```

I have already set all color in css style sheet.
like this:

```
.c1 {
    background-color: #F44336;
}
.c2 {
    background-color: #E91E63;
}
.c3 {
    background-color: #9C27B0;
}
.c4 {
    background-color: #673AB7;
}
```

Now i dont get the color in dom. 
it show `color-code="undefined"`

How can I fix it?

I am sorry for the title. I can't understand what should be the title. So I put this.

**Edit:**
Due to a answer from @Abdul I have corrected my js. But still it shows `color-code="undefined"`. When I console log this it shows

```
rgb(244, 67, 54)                                              main.js:10 
63 undefined                                                  main.js:10
```

Comment: do u have 64 elements with those classes on the page? if you don't have all 64 elements, the rest of your loop will get no elements from the DOM, therefore there will be no color to get

Comment: Yes. I have all 64 li in my web page.

Comment: well then it should't log undefined

Comment: I am using chrome latest on a windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

this line is wrong:

```
var colorMenu = $(Cselector).css( "background-color" );
```

should be:

```
var colorMenu = $('.' + Cselector).css( "background-color" );
```

***OR*** keep your line but change this:

```
var Cselector = ".c" + linum;
                 ^ notice the period
```

see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6551a0ku/)

I would also refactor your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/6551a0ku/2/

```
var eg_color_ul_1 = $('.eg-ul-1');
var eg_color_ul_2 = $('.eg-ul-2');

for (var linum = 1; linum < 5; linum++) {
    var className = 'c' + linum;
    var Cselector = '.' + className;
    var colorMenu = $(Cselector).css( "background-color" );

    eg_color_ul_1.append(getATag(className, colorMenu)),
    eg_color_ul_2.append(getATag(className, colorMenu));

}

function getATag(className, colorMenu) {
  var aTag = "<a class='"
  + className
  + "' color-code='"
  + colorMenu 
  + "'>a</a>";
  return aTag;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Abdul for providing the answer and i tried this. But still show undefined.

Comment: please see the question for 2nd time. I have edited the question.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad, in your example fiddle, you have the DOM elements with the CSS classes on the DOM first, so that is why the css("background-color") returns values. In Shohidul's question, there is no indication that DOM elements matching .c1 ... .c63 exist in the DOM yet, which is (probably) why s/he gets undefined.

Comment: @syazdani if you read the first line of the question: `I have created 64 color buttons in dom by js. they have class name like this:`

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a misunderstanding of where jQuery will pull the background-color property from. The DOM/jQuery doesn't have a direct understanding of the CSS properties you set down *until* you associate them with a DOM element either in the actual DOM, or in a Document Fragment.

```
var eg_color_ul_1 = $('.eg-ul-1');
var eg_color_ul_2 = $('.eg-ul-2');

for (var linum = 1; linum < 65; linum++) {
    var Cselector = ".c" + linum;
    // the problem is here, at this point, there are no dom elements that match .cN so there is no value to return
    var colorMenu = $(Cselector).css( "background-color" );

    eg_color_ul_1.append("<a class=\"c" + linum + "\" color-code=\""+ colorMenu +"\"></a>"),
    eg_color_ul_2.append("<a class=\"c" + linum + "\" color-code=\""+ colorMenu +"\"></a>");

}
```

You can fix this by appending the anchor tags to the DOM first and *then* assigning the color code attribute.

```
var eg_color_ul_1 = $('.eg-ul-1');
var eg_color_ul_2 = $('.eg-ul-2');

for (var linum = 1; linum < 65; linum++) {
    eg_color_ul_1.append("<a class=\"c" + linum + "\"></a>"),
    eg_color_ul_2.append("<a class=\"c" + linum + "\"></a>");
}

for (var linum = 1; linum < 65; linum++) {
    var domElement = $(".c" + linum)
    var colorMenu = domElement.css("background-color")
    domElement.attr('color-code', colorMenu)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with JQuery but if `element.css("property")` is the equivalent of `element.style.property` then that's your problem, the `style` there is referring to the inline `style` attribute and, as you are using a stylesheet, this is returning nothing.

The solution is to instead use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), like so:

```
var eg_color_ul_1=$(".eg-ul-1");
var eg_color_ul_2=$(".eg-ul-2");
for(var linum=1;linum<65;linum++){
  var colorMenu=window.getComputedStyle($(".c"+linum),null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
  eg_color_ul_1.append("<a class=\"c"+linum+"\" data-color-code=\""+colorMenu+"\"></a>");
  eg_color_ul_2.append("<a class=\"c"+linum+"\" data-color-code=\""+colorMenu+"\"></a>");
}
```

I'd also suggest using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) rather than custom attributes to avoid any potential issues.